# Print Python behave context to console

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-behave

Is it possible to print the Pytyhon behave library context to console? I'm able to print individual attributes with `context.foo` but would like to see what all attributes the context has.

Comment: `print(dir(context))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This give me what I was looking for:

```py
print(dir(context))
```